# Remap subset of the y-axis labels with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plt_ticker



x = [0, 5, 9, 10, 15]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

I'd like to use the following dictionary to remap values within the y-axis:

```
remap = {0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three"}
```

Any values which aren't in this dictionary should be mapped to an empty string, `""`.

I've tried using the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plt_ticker


x = [0, 5, 9, 10, 15]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)
remap = {0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three"}


def y_format(x, y):
    return remap.get(y, y)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt_ticker.FuncFormatter(y_format))
```

which gives:

[image]

it seems that I'm off-by-one, but am not too sure how I should handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ax.set_yticklabels`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plt_ticker


x = [0, 5, 9, 10, 15]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)
remap = {0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three"}

ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_yticklabels(map(lambda yy: remap[yy] if yy in remap else '' , y))

plt.show()
```

[image]